# FontAwesome suddenly gibberish in Rails 3.2 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, font-awesome

We have a rails 3 app, it was working great, we deployed it. I had to set up a new computer for development, cloned my repo, set everything up, and now Font Awesome fonts refuse to work (show gibberish). I cloned into my original computer; in my original folder, they work fine. But any new clones do not.

Instead of showing the font, they show the content (gibberish set in the scss file, like '\f010'). This is usually displayed as a strange shape or something, but definitely not the icon. Tried on Mac OS X Mountain Lion and Ubuntu 12.04, Chrome and Firefox.

What we tried:

- Made a new branch in original folder. Updated all gems to newest
  version - I thought the clone might have newer gems that made it
  break somewhere. Original project still looks fine, new clones (and
  checking out the branch) are broken.
- Replaced the .scss and font files from fresh download from the
  fontawesome site.
- Verified path is correct for font files (they seem to be found,
  because Chrome inspector doesn't complain about missing font files -
  if I change the path, it does complain. They just aren't being
  used/used properly)

Gem list in both folders show same gems with same versions.

FontAwesome path is:

> myapp/vendor/assets/stylesheets/FontAwesome

with the sass and fonts folders inside of that.

The only thing changed in the sass was the path line:

> $fontAwesomePath: "FontAwesome/font/fontawesome-webfont" !default;

Which, as I said, seems to work; if I change the path, chrome complains about the missing fonts.

I am using Apache 2, Ruby ree-1.8.7 p-358, Rails 3.2.7, Passenger 3.0.12, RVM 1.14.10, Bundler 1.1.4. Passenger and bundler sit in my global gemset. Here is my Gemfile:

```
# myapp/Gemfile
# The specified versions are to make sure everything is as it is in the
# original folder; didn't make a difference. But the original branch has
#them and is working.

source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.7'

gem 'chronic', '0.6.7'
gem 'enumerated_attribute', '0.2.16'
gem 'exception_notification', '2.6.1'
gem 'google-api-client', '0.4.5'
gem 'her', '~> 0.2.6'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.11'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 2.7.0'
gem 'pdfkit', '0.5.2'
gem 'remotipart', '~> 1.0'
gem 'settingslogic'
gem 'slim-rails'#, '1.0.3'
gem 'validates_timeliness', '~> 3.0.2'
gem 'whenever', '0.7.3', :require => false

group :assets do
  gem 'compass-rails'#, '1.0.3'
  gem 'sass-rails'#, '3.2.5'
end

gem 'coffee-rails'#, '3.2.2'
gem 'uglifier'#, '1.2.7'

group :development do
  gem 'quiet_assets', '1.0.1'
  gem 'thin' , '1.4.1' 
end

gem 'letter_opener', '0.0.2', :group => [:development, :test, :staging]

gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0', :group => [:development, :test]

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.7.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '1.2.1'
  gem 'shoulda', '3.1.1'
end
```

If anyone needs more info just let me know. I've run out of ideas and I'm not getting anywhere, and I'm worried to deploy now and have our prod env messed up!

EDIT: Still not getting results. I updated to Rails 3.2.8 and all gems are at their latest, except for paperclip and factory_girl_rails, which use older versions for Ruby 1.8.7.

Destroyed all my folders, cloned a new one, works fine. Cloned a second, no good. Open first clone in Chrome incognito window, doesn't work. Inspector -> Resources -> Frames -> (site) -> Fonts shows the font files.

Here's an image of what it should look like (left) vs the problem (right):
[image: Problem Fonts]

Comment: Have you tried clear cache on your original computer and see if this issues occur on your computer too?

Comment: @charinten Wow - this was an old question! I've since moved on from this app, and  as far as I can remember never found a solution to this. I am curious if the upvotes to this question were people with similar issues, or just upvotes for another reason. I've not personally run into this since.

Answer (score 0):

try this, i recently had a similar issue,

if you put this at the top of your CSS files,

```
/*
 *= require font-awesome
 */
```

and then use  this **gem 'font-awesome-rails'** it should work